# Retrieve values from multiprocessing library

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

I am trying to use multiprocesing library to compare the performance of my processor on 1 core vs 2 cores.
Therefore I calculate a great product using 1 loop, 2 loops on 1 core, and 2 loops on 2 cores (1 core/loop). The problem is that the value of *D1.result* and *D2.result* are *0* although they are expected to be the product of the "half/loop".
The code is the following:

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Process as Task, freeze_support
N = 10 ** 3
l = [random.randint(2 ** 999, 2 ** 1000 - 1) for x in range(N)]
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
class Loop:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result=0
    def boucle(self,start,end):
        self.result = l[start]
        for v in l[start+1:end]:
            self.result = self.result*v
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__=="__main__":
    print("1 Loop without multiprocessing")
    A=Loop()
    sta = time.time()
    ra=A.boucle(0,N)
    end = time.time()
    print("--> Time :", end - sta)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    print("2 Loops without multiprocessing")
    B1=Loop()
    B2=Loop()
    sta = time.time()
    rb1 = B1.boucle(0, N//2)
    rb2 = B2.boucle(N//2, N)
    rb = B1.result*B2.result
    end = time.time()
    print("--> Time :", end - sta)
    if rb - A.result == 0 :  
        check="OK"
    else :
        check="fail"
    print("--> Check :", check)
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    print("2 Loops with multiprocessing")
    freeze_support()
    D1=Loop()
    D2=Loop()
    v1 = Task(target=D1.boucle, args=(0,N//2))
    v2 = Task(target=D2.boucle, args=(N//2,N))
    sta = time.time()
    v1.start()
    v2.start()
    v1.join()
    v2.join()
    rd = D1.result*D2.result
    end = time.time()
    print("D1",D1.result)
    print("D2",D2.result)
    print("--> Time :", end - sta)
    if rd - A.result == 0 :    
        check="OK"
    else :
        check="fail"
    print("--> Check :", check)
```

The result of this code is :

```
1 Loop without multiprocessing
--> Time : 0.5025153160095215
2 Loops without multiprocessing
--> Time : 0.283463716506958
--> Check : OK
2 Loops with multiprocessing
D1 0
D2 0
--> Time : 0.2579989433288574
--> Check : fail

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why **D1 0** and **D2 0** and not the result of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this code is shown when D1 and D2 are displayed:
In multiprocessing, tasks are executed in a forked process. This process got a copy of the data.
In each forked process the value is properly computed but it is never sent back to main process.

To work around this you can:

- Use shared memory to store the result, but in this case you are limited to C types.  Your numbers do not fit on 64 bits (max integer size in C), so this is not a good solution.
- Use a pool of process, thus data will be shared using queues and you will be able to manage real python types.

This last option requires that "boucle" function returns the result.

Here is the code:

```py
import random
from multiprocessing import Process as Task, freeze_support, Pool
import time

N = 10 ** 3
l = [random.randint(2 ** 999, 2 ** 1000 - 1) for x in range(N)]


# ---------------------------------------------------------------
class Loop:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = 0

    def boucle(self, start, end):
        self.result = l[start]

        for v in l[start + 1:end]:
            self.result = self.result * v

        return self.result


# ---------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("1 Loop without multiprocessing")
    A = Loop()
    sta = time.time()
    ra = A.boucle(0, N)
    end = time.time()
    print("--> Time :", end - sta)
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    print("2 Loops without multiprocessing")
    B1 = Loop()
    B2 = Loop()
    sta = time.time()
    rb1 = B1.boucle(0, N // 2)
    rb2 = B2.boucle(N // 2, N)
    rb = B1.result * B2.result
    end = time.time()
    print("--> Time :", end - sta)
    if rb - A.result == 0:
        check = "OK"
    else:
        check = "fail"
    print("--> Check :", check)
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    print("2 Loops with multiprocessing")
    freeze_support()
    D1 = Loop()
    D2 = Loop()

    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    with pool:
        sta = time.time()
        sta = time.time()
        rb1 = pool.apply_async(B1.boucle, (0, N // 2))
        rb2 = pool.apply_async(B2.boucle, (N // 2, N))

        v1 = rb1.get()
        v2 = rb2.get()

        rd = v1 * v2
        end = time.time()

        print("D1", D1.result)
        print("D2", D2.result)
    print("--> Time :", end - sta)
    if rd - A.result == 0:
        check = "OK"
    else:
        check = "fail"
    print("--> Check :", check)
```

And the result:

```
1 Loop without multiprocessing
--> Time : 0.3473360538482666
2 Loops without multiprocessing
--> Time : 0.18696999549865723
--> Check : OK
2 Loops with multiprocessing
D1 0
D2 0
--> Time : 0.1116642951965332
--> Check : OK
```

You can also use map with the pool to get the value back, but I have not tried it in this case because you only call 2 functions, and pool workers get tasks by "packets of functions - see maxtaskperchild" so it could be possible that only one worker will have taken the 2 functions for itself